# Jemanden singen hören, tanzen sehen

Tags: usage, infinitive, grammar-identification

Man kann die Verben *»hören«* und *»sehen«* mit dem Infinitiv eines anderen Verbs verbinden, um auszudrücken, dass man die vom Infinitiv repräsentierte Tätigkeit wahrnimmt:

> Ich **hörte** Wasser **plätschern**.
>   Heinz will dich **singen hören**.
>
> Ich **sah** Blumen **blühen**.
>   Heinz will dich **tanzen sehen**.

Mir fallen außer *»hören«* und *»sehen«* keine anderen Verben ein, die man in solch einer Konstruktion verwenden könnte.

**Frage 1:**
Gibt es eine spezielle Bezeichnung für diese Konstruktion oder für die spezielle Art des Infinitivs des Verbs, welches *hören/sehen* begleitet?

**Frage 2:**
Gibt es andere Verben als *»hören«* und *»sehen«*, die dasselbe Kunststück vollführen können?

**Frage 3:**
Wenn jemand eine schwülstige und gekünstelte Rede hält, sagt man gerne:

> Der Vortragende **hört** sich wohl gerne selber **reden**.

Ich würde gerne über den Verfasser eines geschriebenen Textes etwas Vergleichbares sagen, aber

> Der Autor **liest** sich wohl gerne selber **schreiben**.

funktioniert nicht. Warum nicht?

Comment: Im Deutschen ist diese Konstruktion weitgehend auf Verben der physischen Wahrnehmung beschränkt. In anderen Sprachen gibt es mehr Möglichkeiten, z.B. kann man im Englischen sagen *I want you to come*, im Deutschen geht das so nicht, man muss einen Nebensatz verwenden.

Comment: @RHa "I want you to come" *könnte* man mit "Ich heiße dich kommen" übersetzen, wenn man kein "zu" gebrauchen will.

Comment: Fachbegriff: AcI (de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusativus_cum_infinitivo). Die Konstruktion ist in anderen Sprachen verbreiteter; im Lateinischen kann man seitenlang im AcI schreiben, weil er zur Notation der indirekten Rede verwendet wird.

Comment: Das ist auf jeden Fall etwas semantisches, worauf du anspielst sind Sinneswahrnehmungen, hören kannst du alles das, was einen Ton erzeugt: singen, sprechen. Sehen kannst du alles, was ein Bild erzeugt, sehr viele Verben lassen sich herauf anwenden, die etwas visuelles entstehen lassen. Fühlen oder spüren kannst du alles, was eine physische Kraft erzeugt.

Comment: Man kann allerdings sagen: *Der Autor liest sich wohl gerne selber.* - Hier das Schreiben anzuhängen, wäre unlogisch, da das Schreiben ja nicht im Moment des Lesens geschieht sondern vorgelagert ist.

Comment: @tofro, so assertive, I like your dirty talk!

Comment: @CarstenS <p style="color:red">☺ - War aber zum Glück nicht mein Beispiel

Comment: Einer meiner Lateinlehrer in der Schule sagte damals: "Der AcI funktioniert mit allen Verben, die im Kopf passieren, also sehen, hören, riechen, sagen, sprechen, denken, fühlen usw." Im Deutschen scheint das nur für die unmittelbaren *Wahrnehmungen* des Kopfes (hören, sehen usw.) zu gelten, und da auch nicht für alle, da *lesen* ja auch im Kopf stattfindet. Aber es findet eben auch keine unmittelbare Wahrnehmung statt: man sieht die Buchstaben, die schon vorher da waren. Deshalb geht *er hört sich reden* aber nicht *er liest sich schreiben*.

Comment: @RHa Die Analogie im Englischen wäre eine andere: I _have_ you come. (sog. 'causative' have) Andere Beispiele: 'I made him come', 'I let him wait'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Frage 1:
>
> Frage 2:

Ich habe folgenden Link im Internet gefunden, der interessant sein könnte:

http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/spezielle-verben/verben-ohne-zu/

Auf der entsprechenden Seite sind unter Anderen die Verben "**helfen**", "**gehen**", "**fahren**" und "**lernen**" genannt, die auf diese Weise gebildet werden. Allerdings wird bei diesen Verben nicht der Akkusativ verwendet, sondern z.B. der Dativ: "Ich helfe **ihm** tragen."

> Frage 2:
>
> Im Deutschen ist diese Konstruktion weitgehend auf Verben der physischen Wahrnehmung beschränkt. – RHa

Außerdem ist mir das Wort "**lassen**" eingefallen, das auf diese Art (mit Akkusativ) gebildet wird: "Ich lasse **ihn** reden."

Auf der anderen Seite scheinen fast alle Verben der Wahrnehmung so eine Konstruktion (mit Akkusativ) zu erlauben:

> Im Dschungel **spürt** man den Tiger nicht kommen, sondern man **riecht** ihn kommen.

.

> Frage 3:
>
> Der Vortragende hört sich wohl gerne selber reden.
>
> Der Autor liest sich wohl gerne selber schreiben.

Der Inhalt der Sätze ist ein anderer:

Der Satz "Er hört sie atmen." besagt, dass eine Person dadurch wahrnimmt, dass eine andere Person atmet, indem die erste Person hört. Entsprechend nimmt der Vortragende im ersten Satz sein eigenes Reden dadurch wahr, dass er etwas (gemint ist implizit: sein eigenes Reden) hört.

Der Satz "Er liest sie atmen." würde besagen, dass eine Person (erst) dadurch wahrnimmt, dass eine andere Person atmet, indem die erste Person liest. Entsprechend würde der Autor im zweiten Satz dadurch wahrnehmen, dass er etwas schreibt, indem er etwas (implizit ist das Geschriebene gemeint) liest. Und das ist eben nicht der Fall.

Comment: "lassen" ist eine andere Ausnahmegruppe. Manche zählen es zu den Modalverben, die auch keinen Infinitiv mit "zu" bilden, andere packen es in eine eigene Ausnahme zusammen mit "bleiben".

Comment: Die verlinkte Seite geht nicht auf das spezifische der AcI-Konstruktion ein, und so funktionieren denn auch die von dir genannten Verben «helfen», «gehen», «fahren» und «lernen» grammatisch anders als diejenigen Verben, um die es dem OP geht.

Comment: @tofro Von der Bildung her (Akkusativ + Infinitiv) entspricht "lassen" meines Erachtens genau den Sinneswahrnehmungsverben. Die Bedeutung ist natürlich eine andere. Aber die Bedeutung zweier unterschiedlicher Verben der Wahrnehmung unterscheidet sich auch. ("Helfen" würde hingegen mit Dativ + Infinitiv gebildet und würde sich daher auch von der Bildung unterscheiden...) Ich bearbeite die Antwort ein wenig.

Comment: @mach "Lassen" wäre Akkusativ + Infinitiv, aber definitiv kein Wahrnehmungsverb.

Answer (score 5):

Ist es nicht eigentlich die Funktion des Infinitivs, dass er es ermöglicht, eine *Tätigkeit* als Objekt mit einem Prädikat zu belegen?

> Ich höre ihn singen

ist für mich jetzt nicht so entscheidend anders als

> Er läßt mich hereinkommen

Ich finde die Form also nicht so sehr besonders.

Die Gruppe von Verben der Wahrnehmung/Empfindung ist *eine* von einigen Ausnahmen, bei denen der Infinitiv nicht mit "zu" steht.

[Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Infinitiv.html) listet dazu *hören*, *sehen*, *fühlen*, *spüren*.

Zu deiner letzten Frage: "Lesen" ist dann offensichtlich kein Verb der Wahrnehmung/Empfindung.

In vielen deutschen Dialekten ist der Infinitiv im Übrigen wesentlich flexibler und kann in noch viel mehr Fällen ohne "zu" verwendet werden. Verständlich: "zu" ist jetzt nicht gerade ein Dialektwort.

> "I fang an schreiben"

Comment: Gute Beobachtung mit den Dialekten. Schwäbisch eben "I fang aa schreiba", "Etz heer mol auf heina!" (Jetzt höre doch mal zu weinen auf!). Aber es gibt ja auch noch andere Beispiele für finite Verbform + Infinitiv auch aus der Standardsprache: *Ich gehe einkaufen*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann *Verben der Bewegung* sind eine andere Gruppe der Ausnahmeverben.

Answer (score 2):

1. *[Accusativus cum infintivo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusativus_cum_infinitivo)* oder normalerweise einfach kurz *AcI.*
2. Canoonet listet die folgenden Verben auf: “hören, sehen, fühlen, spüren, lassen und heissen (= befehlen)” ([canoonet - Satzbaupläne: Hauptpläne: Akkusativ mit Infinitiv](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzbau/Hauptplan/aci.html)).
3. So ist es einfach im Deutschen.

Grammatisch gesehen besteht die Besonderheit des AcI darin, dass das Satzglied im Akkusativ einerseits das Akkusativobjekt bildet und andererseits das logische Subjekt des Verbs im Infinitiv. Beispielsatz (ich konstruiere einen neuen Beispielsatz, in dem die Kasus offensichtlich hervortreten):

> Der Fischer hört den Bach plätschern.

Hier ist das Satzglied «den Bach» das Akkusativobjekt, aber ebenfalls das logische Subjekt zum Infinitiv «plätschern». Der Satz lässt sich also wie folgt umformulieren:

> Der Fischer hört den Bach. Der Bach plätschert.

Dies ist grammatisch gesehen einigermassen ungewöhnlich, denn normalerweise gilt das Subjekt für den ganzen Satz. Es ist aber im Beispielsatz der Bach, der plätschert, und nicht der Fischer.

Answer (score 1):

Etwas Ähnliches [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50159/two-non-modal-verbs-in-a-single-sentence/50172#50172) schon einmal Thema. Das Phänomen ist nicht auf Wahrnehmungsverben beschränkt. Meines Wissen heißen die finiten Verben dieser Konstruktionen "infinitivregierende Verben". Es gibt auch "Infinitiv-mit-zu-regierende Verben" wie *scheinen, pflegen* usw. Eine weitere Untergruppe innerhalb der Infinitiv-ohne-zu-Regierenden sind die Bewegungsverben (*seinen Hund spazieren fahren, laufen gehen, jemanden besuchen kommen*), zu denen man à la limite auch *bleiben* als Nullbewegung rechnen könnte (*irgendwo wohnen bleiben, in der Schule klebenbleiben, die Zeit ist stehengeblieben ...*). Allerdings gibt es unter ihnen auch Partizip-2-regierende Bewegungsverben (*angeschlappt / angeflogen / gelaufen / geritten kommen, verloren / verschütt gehen ...*).

Zu Frage 3 würde ich sagen, dass man sich beim Sprechen ja tatsächlich selbst hört. Ob man beim Schreiben tatsächlich mitliest? Schon irgendwie, als Korrekturleser, eine Art Self-Monitoring. Gemeint ist aber beim Sich-selbst-gerne-reden-Hören, dass die betreffende Person sich selbst bildlich gesprochen so gerne zuhören würde, wie einer anderen Person, deren Redestil ihr gefällt. Im Grunde ist da nur 'der Kerl ist ganz schön selbstgefällig' gemeint, und dass er in seinem Überlegenheitsgefühl gar nicht auf den Gedanken kommt, dass andere auch gerne etwas sagen würden. Daraus ergibt sich als weitere Bedeutung 'er redet zu viel und zu lange und quatscht alle anderen tot'. Das Sprachbild funktioniert nur, wenn Publikum dabei ist, nicht im stillen Kämmerlein. Schreiben mit Publikum erscheint mir schwierig, zumindest ist ein Autor, dem man beim Schreiben im Internet zusehen kann, eine seltene Erscheinung. Das wäre auch ziemlich langweilig, denn die Dynamik des gesprochenen Worts, Mimik, Gestik, auch das Tempo und die Interaktion mit dem Publikum, all das fällt komplett weg. Es wäre ein bisschen wie 'seinen Fingernägeln beim Wachsen zusehen', eher eine meditative Übung.

Außerdem sind *hören - reden* und *lesen - schreiben* nicht analog. Ansatzweise analog wären *er sieht sich schon auf dem Siegertreppchen stehen* oder *er sieht seine Schreibübungen praktisch bereits auf Platz 1 der Bestsellerliste*. Das ist ein weiterer optionaler Bedeutungsanteil von *sich selbst gerne reden hören*: Er redet um des Redens willen, der Inhalt ist völlig sekundär.

---

Erst nachträglich wird mir klar, dass wahrscheinlich eine AcI-Konstruktion gemeint ist. Eine zumindest ähnliche Konstruktion haben:

> **legen**: Sie hat den Kleinen schlafen gelegt.
>
> **helfen**: Wer kann noch helfen Stachelbeeren pflücken?
>
> **lassen**: Der Graf ließ die Pferde anspannen.
>
> **schicken**: Man schickte den Arzt holen.
>
> **führen**: Sie führte ihre neue Kollektion spazieren.
>
> **lehren**: jemanden reiten lehren (veraltet) (vlg. *jn das Fürchten lehren*)
>
> **beibringen**: jemandem Tango tanzen beibringen (meist aber mit Artikel)

Wahrscheinlich gibt es davon noch mehr.

Einen AcI, bei dem der **Akkusativ des AcI als Subjekt einer Nicht-AcI-Konstruktion** realisiert werden kann, gibt es noch bei

> **lassen**: Es ließ die Kinder weiter spielen.
>
> **haben**: Er hat den Schrank jetzt im Flur stehen. Er hat einen Freund bei sich wohnen

(Für mich) erstaunlicherweise können wir nicht analog zu den Wahrnehmungsverben sagen:

> **erleben**: **Wir erleben gerade alle die gesamte Natur den Bach runtergehen* oder **Er hat im Laufe seines Lebens viele Staaten zusammenbrechen erlebt.*

Oder doch?