# “Noch nie hatte er ein totes Tier wieder lebendig werden sehen.” – why not “gesehen”?

Tags: verb, grammaticality, past-participle

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37840*
>   *[Why no perfect participle? "Sie hat sich scheiden lassen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/70)*

---

> Noch nie hatte er ein totes Tier wieder lebendig werden sehen.

In above sentence, why isn’t it *gesehen?*

> Noch nie hatte er ein totes Tier wieder lebendig werden gesehen.

My question is about using the infinitive form for verbs of perception like *sehen* or *hören*. I learned soon after my post that they don’t use participle form for those verbs when in perfect tense.

Comment: Moderator’s notice: Cleaning up the comments as the duplicate discussion seems to have been resolved. Please also note [this Meta discussion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/807/2594).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a construction that is called *Ersatzinfinitiv* in use in certain cases of *Perfekt* clauses.

Usually *Perfekt* is built by combining the perfect participle of the verb plus *haben* or *sein*.

> Ich **habe** Knödel **gekocht**
>
> In **bin** nach München **gefahren**.

However, when there is an infinitve clause depending on the verb 
as in

> Ich **sehe** dich ***kommen*** (*Präsens*)
>
> Ich **sah** dich ***kommen*** (*Imperfekt*)

Then there *Partizip Perfekt* is sometimes replaced by *Infinitiv*.

> Ich **habe** dich kommen **sehen**. (*Perfekt* with *Ersatzinfinitiv*)
>
> RATHER NOT: Ich **habe** dich kommen **gesehen** (*Perfekt* the usual way, i.e. with *Partizip Perfekt*)

#### Where to use it

This construction is in use with a number of of verbs (and then the *Perfekt mit Ersatzinfinitiv* would usually be preferable):

**lassen**

> Sie haben sich scheiden lassen.
>
> NOT: Sie haben sich scheiden gelassen.
>
> Ich habe das dann bleiben lassen.
>
> NOT: Ich habe das dann bleiben gelassen.

**müssen**

> Er hat sie nehmen müssen.
>
> NOT: Er hat sie nehmen gemusst.
>
> Das hättest du länger garen müssen.
>
> NOT: Das hättest du länger garen gemusst.

**können**

> Ich habe ihn treffen können.
>
> NOT: Ich habe ihn treffen gekonnt.
>
> Ich habe ihn nicht ausstehen können.
>
> NOT: Ich habe ihn nicht ausstehen gekonnt.

**dürfen**

> Sie hat ihn küssen dürfen.
>
> NOT: Sie hat hin küssen gedurft.
>
> Wir haben sie nicht besuchen dürfen.
>
> NOT: Wir haben sie nicht besuchen gedurft.

**wollen**

> Wir haben Dich sehen wollen.
>
> NOT: Wir haben dich sehen gewollt.
>
> Ich habe mein Zimmer aufräumen wollen.
>
> NOT: Ich habe mein Zimmer aufräumen gewollt.

**sollen**

> Ich hätte ihn ihn sitzenlassen sollen.
>
> NOT: Ich hätte ihn sitzenlassen gesollt
>
> Die FDP hätte weiterverhandeln sollen
>
> NOT: Die FDP hätte weiterverhandeln gesollt.

Note: here we see that this is also used in *Konjunktiv* clauses.

**mögen**

> Sie hat mich nicht sehen mögen.
>
> NOT: Sie hat mich nicht sehen gemocht.

**können**

> Er hat nicht kommen können.
>
> NOT: Er hat nicht kommen gekonnt.
>
> Ich habe einfach nicht mehr weiterarbeiten können.
>
> NOT: Ich habe einfach nicht mehr weiterarbeiten gekonnt.

**sehen**

> Das habe ich kommen sehen
>
> RATHER NOT: Das habe ich kommen gesehen

<sub>Note: that would be the answer to your actual question: With *sehen* and *Perfekt* wie usually use the *Ersatzinfinitiv* construction. It is just so.</sub>

**hören**

> Wir haben ihn singen hören.
>
> RATHER NOT: Wir haben ihn singen gehört.

Note: my personal impression is that with *hören* and *sehen* the *Partizip Perfekit* versions are still a viable option, but I am not sure how other native speakers would see this; perhaps I have a southern German bias here. E.g. in Swabian the usual form would be: *I han de komma gsäa* - *Ich habe dich kommen gesehen*, as opposed to *I han it komma kenna* - **Ich habe nicht kommen können".

#### Attention with longer infitive clauses

However, when the infivitive construction consists itself of more elements, e.g. instead of simple *Wir haben hin singen hören* rather

> Wir haben ihn **Geige spielen** hören

or even

> Wir haben ihn **lang und ausgiebig Geige spielen** hören
>
> Wir haben ihn **täglich lang und ausgiebig Geige spielen** hören

it seems, the "regular" form of *Perfekt* comes back into play:

> Wir haben ihn **lang und ausgiebig Geige spielen** gehört
>
> Wir haben ihn **täglich lang und ausgiebig Geige spielen** gehört

as the preferable one.

> RATHER NOT: Wir haben ihn täglich lang und ausdauernd Geige spielen hören

Let's try it with *sehen*:

> (1) Das habe ich in dieser Eile nicht sich zutragen sehen
>
> (2) Das habe ich in dieser Eile nicht sich zutragen gesehen
>
> (3) Er hat sie gestern mit einem anderen rummachen sehen.
>
> (4) Er hat sie gestern mit einem anderen rummachen gesehen.

In these pairs I find it difficult to decide which (1 or 2; 3 or 4) is the "better" or "more acceptable" or "unmarked" way to say it.

Anyway, both forms of expression are part of oral language, not so much written language - there you would choose other syntactical structures anyway, e.g.

> Er hat gesehen, wie sie gestern mit einem anderen Zärtlichkeiten austauschte.
>
> In dieser Eile konnte ich nicht erkennen, dass die Dinge sich in dieser Form entwickeln würden.

#### Semantical differentiation

As commenter PiedPieper correctly states, in longer infinitive clauses there may be a different meaning attributed to the two constructions:

> Ich habe den Tsunami kommen gesehen (*Normales Perfekt*)

would mean a concrete situation of watching advance a concrete tsunami wave, whereas

> Ich habe den Tsunami kommen sehen (*Perfekt mit Ersatzinfinitiv*)

would mean a general prediction that there would be a tsunami at some time in the future.

Let's try this once more:

> Ich habe den Hamster laufen gelassen

seems to be meaning that the person speaking has done something so that the hamster could run (probably in his wheel), in any case some concrete activity, whereas

> Ich habe den Hamster laufen lassen

would definitely tend to be meaning "I let him go", i.e. I opened the door of his cage, and possibly also the door of the house, and now he disappeared - probably for ever - in the garden.

However, these differences are really tiny. They will appear only when you juxtapose two sentences. Otherwise, it may well happen that Fritz says "Ich habe den Hamster laufen gelassen" and still means that he (the hamster) disappeared in the garden.

#### Trying a theory

I think a good hypothesis is: In cases where both *normales Perfekt* and *Perfekt mit Ersatzinfinitv* produce acceptable sentences, the proposition with *Ersatzinfinitiv* would mean something more "infinite", and the proposition with *normalem Perfekt* would mean some more "finite" action. By

> Ich habe die drei Tenöre singen gehört

I focus on the fact that I have heart them (at whatever point in time). The important thing is that I did it. It is so to say one of my achievements in life. Nobody can take it away from me. It is a finite and finalised action. Whereas by

> Ich habe die drei Tenöre singen hören

I rather focus on the very process of hearing them. I position myself in the situation of actual, ongoing listening. The action is not finalised, or perhaps more precisely: I present to my interlocutor a situation where I am in the middle of listening to the three singers.

However, it may well be that we are now over-stretching the rule of rules in language here. Probably all this is more a question of tradition ("things are being said just so"), and people use both forms of expression without really sensing a difference.

---

Note: this answer builds upon the answer by RedDwight to Question 70 in this forum ([Why no perfect participle? "Sie hat sich scheiden lassen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70/why-no-perfect-participle-sie-hat-sich-scheiden-lassen)) and uses many of its examples, although with additional considerations.

Comment: You might want to credit Hans Adler, who originally came up with the Tsunami example here https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70/why-no-perfect-participle-sie-hat-sich-scheiden-lassen

Comment: @Pied: Asking "why" related to phenomena of language often does not lead anywhere (unless you are interested in the history of language(s) and its development through centuries). - A lot of forms in use are in use because using them (and not others) is something like an agreement of the users of that language. Or call it: tradition, or call it: that's just how it is being done.

Comment: @Pied. PS: Oh, and by the way, I think I anyway answered the question. The question was "Why isn't it *Ich habe noch nie ein totes Tieer wieder lebendig werden gesehen*", and the answer says that usually with *sehen* we use the construction with *Ersatzinfinitiv*.

Comment: I agree with you that the question *why* a construction exists is pointless. Maybe I should write my own answer :)

Comment: `Er hat sie nehmen müssen.`  if `müssen` is used in the perfect tense, when is `gemusst` used?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to focus on your specific sentence rather trying to give a very comprehensive answer.

First of all, your expectation is completely comprehensible. In all common cases the Plusquamperfekt of *"Er sieht etwas"* is *"Er hatte etwas gesehen"*.

But in case that the object of *sehen* is a composition with the infinite form of another verb, like in

> Er sieht *ihn fliegen*.

there is an additional **special rule** overruling the common one.
According to this special rule, the Plusquamperfekt is now **not**:

> *Er hatte *ihn fliegen* **gesehen**.   <= wrong in most cases

but

> Er hatte *ihn fliegen* **sehen**.

This rule applies not only to *sehen* but to all modal verbs and the verbs *brauchen*, *heißen* and *lassen*, and sometimes to *hören*, *fühlen*, *helfen* too.

For more examples, have a look into the example section of the Wikipedia article [Ersatzinfinitiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv).

Comment: Nice short answer, but I do not understand where you took the "Er sieht ihn fliegen" sample sentence from. It was not in the original question, was it?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann No, it wasn't. It's a short simple sentence with a simple object. Just to keep the very basic structure of the original sentence. No magic behind.