# Two non-modal verbs in a single sentence

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, verb-usage

> Abends gehen wir alle spazieren.

or

> Abends spazieren wir alle.

Which one is correct? I think second one is correct because in the first sentence ***gehen***, is used like a modal verb due to which the second verb ***spazieren*** moved to the end. I haven't seen this type of sentence structure till now for non-modal verbs.

I just posted this question here because while I was going through some tutorial I came across the first sentence as an example for the time adverb 'abends'.

Comment: Why shouldn't *gehen* be a modal verb? I am *going to* remind you, that it well is in French "Je vais te dire; Je vais faire un promenade; Je vais en promenade". On the other hand, it works syntactically like most other compound verbs, *Aufschrei, aufschreien*, "abends schreien wir auf", "Spaziergang - spazieren-gehen", except for the *-en-*, a morpheme that is so versatile that I wouldn't be too sure that it was an infinitive marker. *arbeiten gehen* is comparable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some "normal" verbs can be used as if they were modals. These include:

> Sie **sehen** es kommen.
>
> Wir **helfen** Kartoffeln schälen.
>
> Sie **hören** das Gras wachsen.
>
> Wir **lassen** ihn ruhen.
>
> Sie **lernen** sprechen.
>
> Wir **lehren** sie fahren.
>
> Sie **fühlen** es schmerzen.
>
> Sie **kommen** ihn holen.
>
> Wir **gehen** wandern.

The verb in the infinitive explains the conjugated verb.

Comment: This phenomenon exists in English too: "I saw it coming", "I will go skiing"

Comment: In English, it's with the present participle instead of the infinitive, though. In German, there's a difference between *Ich sah es kommen.* – I saw it while **it** was coming. and *Ich sah es kommend.* – I saw it while **I** was coming.

Comment: All those examples except the last one contain a noun object. That's a slight difference.

Comment: "Ich sah es kommend" is virtually non-existent. That comparison is not apt.

Comment: There's no clear boundary between a modal verb and a non-modal verb. It's just that the rules of grammar in a particular language may make a contrast. English shows this particularly well. Compare "I am going to the cinema to see a film" and "I am going to see a film". You can see how the removal of "to the cinema" makes the "going" become modal. It also shows how the modal meaning evolved from the basic one. We need to study modal verbs because (1) they may have different grammar (from non-modal verbs and from each other) and because the meaning may be non-obvious or used to make tenses.

Comment: Grammar has to take a systematic approach. But most languages aren't systematic, and German is no exception.

Answer (score 6):

There are many more double verb constructions in German:

- **bleiben**: sitzen / liegen / stehen / stecken bleiben
- **bleiben**: irgendwo wohnen bleiben: wir sind erst mal da wohnen geblieben / irgendwo mit dem Ärmel hängen bleiben / das ist mir haften geblieben [= eine bleibende Erinnerung]
- **fahren**: einkaufen / schwimmen / jemanden besuchen fahren / etwas spazieren fahren
- **haben**: ein Bild an der Wand hängen / den Schreibtisch am Fenster stehen / die Hand auf dem Tisch liegen haben
- **kommen**: jemanden besuchen / jemandem helfen kommen
- **legen**: sich / ein Kind schlafen legen
- **heißen** (veraltet): man hieß ihn warten
- **schicken**: man schickte sie ihren Vater holen / die Kinder schlafen schicken / den Vater einkaufen schicken
- **führen**: die Omas führen ihre Enkel spazieren / an den ersten warmen Tagen führen die Frauen wieder ihre Kleider spazieren [≈ stolz herzeigen]
- **tragen**: spazieren tragen (der Mann hatte seinen neuen Schläger in einem geheimnisvollen schwarzen Koffer auf einer Rennstrecke spazieren getragen; einen Chihuahua in der Handtasche spazieren tragen)
- **machen**: von sich reden machen / jemanden etwas glauben machen / etwas vergessen machen
- **spielen**: fangen/Fangen spielen / die Kinder spielen einkaufen/Einkaufen
- **üben**: vor dem Spiegel tanzen üben / etwas laut vorlesen üben
- **beibringen**: jemandem / sich selbst lesen / Klavier spielen beibringen
- ...

To be continued.

Comment: *lassen* could be added