# lassen, hören, sehen, helfen benehmen sich wie Modalverben - Beispiele

Tags: meaning, verb, sentence-structure, modal-verb

*Lassen + Vollverb* benimmt sich wie ein Modalverb. Normalerweise sollte den folgenden Satz richtig sein:

> Ich hoffe, dass wir Sie nicht zu lange haben warten lassen.

Könnten Sie das bestätigen? Welche andere Verben benehmen sich auch so? Ich habe schon bemerkt, das sich *lassen, sehen* und *hören* so verhalten. Mein Grammatikbuch nennt auch *helfen.* Was wäre ein Beispiel mit *helfen* im Perfekt oder Plusquamperfekt?

Ein anderes Beispiel: Sind die folgenden Sätze korrekt?

> Er hörte den Schnee auf den Dächern tauen und in der Nähe des Brunnens fallen.

(Das klingt ziemlich gut für mich.)

> Er hat den Schnee auf den Dächern tauen und in der Nähe des Brunnens fallen hören.

Der doppelte Infinitiv kommt mir seltsamer vor.

Comment: "Der doppelte Infinitiv" ist der Ersatzinfinitiv. Wikipedia hat einen [Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv) darüber und es gibt mehrere Fragen darüber auf dieser Website.

Comment: Eine der Ersatzinfinitiv-Fragen ist [diese](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/70/).

Comment: Very good answers here: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/50159/35111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only going to be a partial answer, but I noticed that the previous version of this question didn't get any answers. German grammars seem to define "modal" verbs as the verbs which fall on a canonical list: *dürfen*, *können*, *mögen*, *müssen*, *sollen* and *wollen*. Coincidentally, these are six of the seven preterite-present verbs, the remaining one being *wissen*. But there are several other verbs which, like a modal verb, require the infinitive of another verb as an "object". (The technical term for this is apparently [Catenative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb).) There are several verbs of perception like this: *sehen*, *hören*, etc. For example: *Ich sehe dich rennen.* As you mentioned, *lassen* is another one: *Ich lasse dich laufen.* These are not exactly the same as modal verbs though, since they require an additional accusative object not required by the second verb. So with *müssen*, the basic sentence plan with an intransitive verb is subject+*müssen*+verb, but the basic sentence plan with *lassen* is subject+*lassen*+accusative object+verb. These verbs seem to be exceptions though since it seems more typical to use the *zu* infinitive rather than the bare infinitive: *Ich bitte dich zu laufen.*

I did mention this is only a partial answer and I don't have a list of such exceptions. One of them is *helfen*, as you mentioned. In that case the *zu* seems to be optional depending on the circumstances; I'm not totally clear on the details myself. But I don't think there are any general rules and it appears that usage varies for individual verbs. Another example is *Wir gehen spazieren.*

Apologies for answering in English; a long discussion in German would be a bit much for me.

PS. It's apparent from some of the comments that I was unclear on something. I didn't mean to say that *only* verbs that take an accusative object can be exceptions. I just meant that *lassen* and the perception verbs do, which is perhaps a reason for not considering them "true" modal verbs. As Tilman Schmidt pointed out, *helfen* actually takes a dative object. Also *spazieren gehen* (no space prior to 1996) is considered a single verb, so not a good example. But *gehen* does seem to combine with a number of other verbs in a very "modal" manner, so to me it's still an edge case.

Wiktionary has a [list of English catenative verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs). It would be nice to have something similar for German verbs, but I haven't been able to find it if such a thing exists. (The link in David Vogt's comment above seems like a good start though.) Both English and German make a distinction between the to/*zu* infinitive and the bare infinitive. English sometimes also uses a gerund where German would use the infinitive, which complicates things on the English side. According to the list, there are four verbs, other than modal verbs, which take a bare infinitive: "dare" (especially in the negative), "help" (the "to" is optional), and "come/go" (to me these are questionable). Since German and English are related, if distantly, I imagine the list for German is similar with allowances for the gerund.

Comment: Note that _helfen_ differs from _sehen_ or _lassen_ in that it takes a Dativ object. "Ich helfe _dir_ tragen" as opposed to "Ich sehe _dich_ laufen."

Comment: "Wir gehen spazieren" is something different entirely. It is a conjugated form of the Trennverb _spazierengehen_.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt What about *Wir gehen essen*? (Or *wir sind dann mal essen*, for that matter.)

Comment: @Tilman Schmidt: On *Wir gehen spazieren*, that makes sense, though DWDS lists it as a phrasal verb *gehen spazieren*. Other combinations are possible as well: I found *Sie ist wandern gegangen*, *Ich will tanzen gehen* in the DWDS usage database. It's hard to tell if they're phrasal verbs or *gehen* combined with another verb; the conjugation and word order seem to be the same either way.

Comment: Sure, there is _gehen_ with an infinitive, but in my opinion it doesn't qualify as a modal verb, and in any event it never has an accusative object. Even in "Ich gehe sie besuchen" the _sie_ isn't an accusative object to _gehen_, but to _besuchen_.

Comment: @Tilman Schmidt: Yes, *gehen* seems to be a special case. I think the main difference is that while a canonical modal verb can combine with any other verb, *gehen* seems to be limited to just a few. You don't say *Sie ist schreiben gegangen* or *Ich will existieren gehen.* (At least I think you don't, it seems unlikely at best.) Perhaps it's just simpler to declare the *gehen* compounds as phrasal verbs.

Comment: _Sie ist schreiben gegangen_ seems perfectly fine to me as a native speaker. I can easily imagine a situation where I would say it exactly like that. _Ich will existieren gehen_ does sound weird, but only for semantic reasons. Compare also the cynical order _Geh sterben_ sometimes heard in heated debates.